# Support for conditional logic in Slack Workflow Builder

Tags: slack

I’m in the process of building automations in a Slack channel using Slack [Workflow Builder](https://slack.com/help/articles/360035692513-Guide-to-Workflow-Builder). I was going through this [blog post](https://slack.com/blog/productivity/efficiency-workflow-builder) which talks about adding support for conditional (if-then) statements in the workflow builder, however i couldn’t find any other details related to it. Wondering to see if someone else had more details or if the feature was even released.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was never released.

The sample approval workflow linked from the post (https://slack.com/slack-tips/approve-travel-requests) still shows the second-workflow-after-responding-with-emoji workaround:

> Previously, the manager would have had to create an additional workflow for people to use based on their answers. Branching has been one of our biggest customer requests, and we can’t wait to see how you build with it.

Conditionals in the workflow builder is currently still one of the most requested slack features (see e.g. [When will If/Then steps come to workflow builder?](https://forums.slackcommunity.com/s/question/0D53a000080b4VtCAI/when-will-ifthen-steps-come-to-workflow-builder-this-was-meant-to-arrive-sometime-in-late-2021-so-just-curious-if-it-will-still-make-it-this-year?language=en_US) on https://forums.slackcommunity.com).